# Am I loading images twice via Manifest and CSS?

Tags: javascript, createjs

I have a question around using createjs and loading images in a manifest. In the example below both images are displayed into a div with the css class .background. My question is in //B is the image reloaded again in the css because I am only using the path from the manifest and setting the background-image attribute in the css? The reason for using a manifest to load the images is so that all the images are downloaded first and then displaying the page. If the image2 is loading twice once in the manifest and then again in the css it I do not have it working as intended.

```
 manifest = [
      {src:"images/img1.jpg", id:"image1"},
      {src:"images/img2.jpg", id:"image2"},
 ]

 loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
 loader.loadManifest(manifest);

 loader.on("complete", handleComplete, this);

 function handleComplete(){
      //A
      var _img1 = loader.getResult("image1");
      $(".background").append(_img1);//writes <img> into .background div
      //B
      var _img2 = loader.getResult("image2");
      $(".background").css({"background-image": 'url('+_img2.src+')'});
 }
```

Comment: have a look at the browser's network requests in the dev tools: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index#improving-network-performance

Comment: You may get a duplicate request, but the second one should be pulled from the cache.

Comment: @Lanny that is what I was thinking about the image already being cached so would you say that this is acceptable or is there a better way of doing this?